# Flexbox layout wider than browser

Tags: css, layout, flexbox

**expected output**: A horizontal line, and the word "testing" below, with no horizontal scrollbar.

**actual output**: A horizontal line with the word "testing" below, but there a horizontal scrollbar, which can be used to move roughly `5px`, regardless of browser width.

This is the minimum code required to reproduce the problem:

```css
body {
  margin: auto;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

hr {
  min-width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<html>
<body>

<section>
  <hr>
  <span>
testing.
  </span>
</section>

</body>
</html>
```

As you can see with "run snippet", you can scroll to the right and make the "t" in testing partially off the page.

**Questions**:

1. Why? How do I make a flexbox layout that uses only the width of the browser? I thought that adding `body { width: 100vw;}` would help, but it doesn't appear to change anything.
2. How can I debug this behavior without asking SO for help? If I take away any of the CSS lines, the problem disappears, but so does the formatting I desire, so I can't say which of them is at fault. How could I figure out what the problem is on my own?

Comment: box-sizing is what you want to know about ;)  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/box-sizing

Comment: hr comes with a default border

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all: your flex layout is working fine! The issue lies within the `<hr>` element, which sneakily takes up some horizontal space. It has borders on both sides – 1px each.

Here are three different solutions, take your pick!

**Get rid of the borders**

```
hr {
  min-width: 100%;
  border-left: none;
  border-right: none;
}
```

**Subtract the border widths from the total**

```
hr {
  min-width: calc(100% - 2px);
}
```

**Change the element's box-sizing**

```
hr {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  min-width: 100%;
}
```

Comment: It is actually a total of 2px added to the width, as a full 1px will be added to each side. So your second example should be `min-width: calc(100% - 2px);`, and change "– 0.5px each" to "– 1px each". Other than that, you came up with the same thing that I did.

Comment: @chris you are right, edited!